# Creating multiple polygon features based on the number of point features contained

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-relationship

Software: ArcGIS Desktop 10.x or ArcGIS Pro

I have a polygon dataset, and a point dataset. Any number of points (or zero points) may intersect with the polygon. I need to generate a new polygon dataset which contains polygon with the attributes of points which intersect them. Ordinarily this would just be a spatial join, however I need a separate polygon feature for each intersecting point.

I need this to be achieved via a new dataset, rather than relating the point table to the polygon table.

I feel like there is a built-in way to do this in ArcMap, but can't place it.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood is this not simply changing the join operation parameter in spatial join to JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY? You would then get as many polygons as there are intersecting points?

Comment: You're absolutely correct.